# How to host twisted python code to the Internet?

Tags: server, protocols, twisted, endpoint, python-3.9

Currently I Have This Following Code Which Simply Echo's The Data Which Is Sent To The Server and Shows The Number Of Active Connections In The Server To The Clients and Sends Some Info.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol , Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint


connections = -1

class echo_simple(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
            global connections
            connections += 1
            self.transport.write(f'Number of active connections in the server are: {connections} '.encode('utf-8'))
    def connectionLost(self,*args , **kwargs):
        global connections
        connections -= 1
        print(':: N :: A Connection Just Closed :: N ::')

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print(f':C: {data} ')
        self.transport.write("\n Server Successfully Received Your Message!".encode('utf-8'))
        self.transport.write(f"\n |THE MESSAGE YOU SENT IS : {data}|".encode('utf-8'))
        self.transport.write(f'\n Closing The Connection As This is Just An Echo Server'.encode('utf-8'))
        self.transport.loseConnection()


class Server_factory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print(" |^INFO^| Created An Instance ")
        return echo_simple()



endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8009)
endpoint.listen(Server_factory())
reactor.run()
```

My Problem Is The Server Is Currently Listening In The **LocalHost** , I want to host this in the **internet** globally !

Say for example i have an domain called **[www.examplecode.com](http://www.examplecode.com)**

Instead of listening in the localhost , how to change my code so that it listens to the **[www.examplecode.com](http://www.examplecode.com)** instead of **localhost** ?

Answer (score 3):

You need the domain to point to a server, that runs this code.
When you buy the domain, the registrar you buy it from usually gives you an interface to setup the dns configuration, usually you'll setup an AA or CNAME record to point to the ip or existing other domain that points to the server you will use to run the code.

You will usually rent a server from another company (there are *plenty* of them), that will run in a data center and will be taken care of, connect to that server, and deploy your code on it (often through ssh), and make it listen on 0.0.0.0 so it accepts connections from anywhere. You then get the IP of this server, and use it to setup the DNS in the interface provided by your registrar.

Alternatively, you can use a computer at your home, if you configure your router to direct connections on the 440 and 80 port to the local ip of this PC, and you put the ip of your home connection in the registrar DNS configuration (hopefully you have a static ip though).

Anyway, it's a bit of a wide subject for a stackoverflow question (and it might not even be on topic for stackoverflow, maybe it's more a serverfault question, or a superuser, one.